# Having trouble creating an object within a switch statement, "Object cannot be resolved" in later code (java)

Tags: java, object, switch-statement

I am writing a method that takes in a string variable `type` that is used to determine which list class to implement. The method uses a switch statement to create the appropriate type of list using the variable name `newList`.

The switch statement looks like this:

```
switch (type) {
    case "unsorted": {
        UnsortedList newList = new UnsortedList();
        break;
    }
    case "sorted": {
        SortedList newList = new SortedList();
        break;
    }
    case "new sorted": {
        NewSortedList newList = new NewSortedList();
        break;
    }
    default: {
        System.out.print("Something went wrong! List type unrecognized. I have initialized newList to be an unsorted list.");
        UnsortedList newList = new UnsortedList();
    }
}
```

According to this, I believe that `newList` will always be instantiated due to the default case of the switch statement. However I receive the compile error "newList cannot be resolved".

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: The scope of `newList` is the individual `{ }` blocks.  It's not visible anywhere else.

Comment: Because you create the list inside the switch,you cannot access it from outside, it's out of scope

Comment: How are you using `newList`? Do these classes share a common interface?

Comment: @shmosel the classes did not initially share a common interface, but contained the same methods. I easily implemented a common interface `List` which can be seen in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `newList` is being created into too small of a scope. Scopes in Java are denoted by `{}`. A variable only exists in scopes of the same level or higher of the scope of its creation.

For example:

```
public class ScopeClass(){ //this is the start of the class level scope
    private String classString = "this can been seen anywhere in the class";
    public void scopeMethod(){ //this starts the method level scope
        private String methodString = "this is only visible in the method";
        { //start of internal scope block
            private String internalString = "only visible in this scope block";
        } 
    }
}
```

To make your `newList` visible outside of the `switch` scope, try this:

```
List newlist; // make sure all of your various List types are compatible. 
switch (type){
    case "unsorted":    
    {
        newList = new UnsortedList();
        break;
    }
    case "sorted":      
    {
        newList = new SortedList();
        break;
    }
    case "new sorted":  
    {
        newList = new NewSortedList();
        break;
    }

    default:
    {
        System.out.print("Something went wrong! List type unrecognized. I have initialized newList to be an unsorted list.");
        newList = new UnsortedList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the prior comments answered the question. You create several different local newList fields that immediately go out of scope.

The solution is to create List newList outside the switch. Note that it will be limited, however, to the methods specified by list, so you won't be able to access sorting methods.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an interface for the list types called `List` and instantiated `newList` as type `List` before the switch statement. This allowed `newList`to be visible outside of the switch and still gain the properties of each list type.

Here's a revised version of my code:

```
    List newList;
    switch (type)
    {
        case "unsorted":    
        {
            newList = new UnsortedList();
            break;
        }
        case "sorted":      
        {
            newList = new SortedList();
            break;
        }
        case "new sorted":  
        {
            newList = new NewSortedList();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            System.out.print("Something went wrong! I have initialized newList to be an unsorted list");
            newList = new UnsortedList();
        }
    }
```

Thank you to everyone for your help. I'm still learning so every comment helps!

Comment: Since you're new, please be sure to vote for, and accept, the best answer to your question. This will make it easier for others to find the answer if they have a similar question.